# How to change colors in a grouped barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have this code to graph the total amount of sales of a certain product per month during three different years:

```
#plt.figure(figsize=())
p = [1, 0, -1]
pos = 0
for i in np.sort(item_20949.year.unique()):
    x = item_20949.month[item_20949.year == i].unique()
    x = np.sort(x)
    y = item_20949[item_20949.year == i].groupby('month').sum().item_cnt_day

    #x = np.arange(len(x))  # label locations
    width = 0.4  # width of the bars

    plt.bar(x + p[pos] * width/2, y, width/2, label= str(i))

    pos += 1

    plt.xlabel('mes')
    plt.ylabel('cantidad de unidades vendidas')
    plt.legend()

#plt.savefig('image_data/pete2')

plt.show()
```

[image: And this is the output]

But what I'm trying to do is to change the colors per each group.

Comment: Before the loop: `colors = ['gold', 'limegreen', 'deepskyblue']`.   To plot one of the bar plots: `plt.bar(..., color=color[i])`

Comment: I tried this but I got the following error: ``` list index out of range ```

Comment: Oops. I forgot the 's' in `color=colors[i]`. If there are more than 3 years, you need more than  colors. Try `plt.bar(..., color=colors[i % len(colors)])` to always get a valid color independent of how large `i` grows.